# Performing find/replace in Xcode for the open tabs only

Tags: iphone, xcode, ide

Is there a way to find/replace just in the source files that are open in tabs and not any other ones? Or is it another handicap of Xcode compared to Visual Studio?

Comment: try cmd + shift + f to find in all source file

Comment: Find & Replace: Cmd + Option + F
Find & Replace in Workspace: Cmd + Option + Shift + F

Comment: @Bala It's not what the question is about.

Comment: Congratulations on tagging an actual Xcode question with the Xcode tag! :)

Comment: @Almo Good point. I just realized how often the Xcode tag is mistakenly used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do it. I don't think many people use tabs in Xcode. The find-and-replace bar remembers what you type in though, so you can select each file one at a time from the menu on the left side, hit alt+command+f on the keyboard, and replace all.